# Store Django filter_backends search keyword

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I want to store the keyword that filter_backend uses to search.

This is the class being used.

```
class SearchListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = TrainingDetail.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TrainingDetailSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['^course_name']
```

The URL being called is:

```
http://localhost:8003/api/company/search/?search=Danphe&ordering=-created_date
```

So, basically I want to store the word Danphe. How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Do you want to search for `Danphe` as the `course_name`?

Comment: @Metalgear The search functionality is working proper. I just want to extract that keyword and store it into separate table in database.